# How to align the Integer value in vue js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vuetify.js

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
   <i class="el-icon-error tst1 " style="font-size: 50px;"/><br>
   <div class="my-auto"> {{this.dashBoardData.closedTicketsCount}}</div><br>
   <span style="font-size: 20px;">Closed</span>
</div>
```

**this.dashBoardData.closedTicketsCount is the INTEGER value . I can't align that integer . I tried many method But nothing won't work . So suggest some idea to align .**

Comment: How do you want to align, center alignment or let alignment, dow you have complete code and template screenshot what you are trying to achieve..

Comment: I want center alignment .

Comment: Can you create a codepen or update your question with complete code, That would really help to solve your issue easier..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure about what you mean, but is this something:

```
<v-layout row justify-center align-center>
    <div>{{this.dashBoardData.closedTicketsCount}}</div>
    <div style="font-size: 20px;">Closed</div>
</v-layout>
```

Then the this.dashBoardData.closedTicketsCount is aligned to the text.